# Strange behavior related to FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates()

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I'm writing a Android app and there's a strange behavior related to FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates() that I've searched on SO and none of the other related questions solved my problem.

Apparently the requestLocationUpdates do not trigger the onLocationChanged() method all the times; I'm saying this because I'm cleaning my app's data on emulator for each run and sometimes the onLocationChanged() is triggered, sometimes not (most of under some conditions like run the app for the second time w/o cleaning the app's data or after making a user data's wipe i.e)

Below you can find my code (links from pastebin, I don't want to create any visual overload here)

Main Activity: http://pastebin.com/XiRrcR11

MapHandler: http://pastebin.com/HELnhaxy

Another problem is, oddly enough, if I use a anonymous inner class in the MapHandler in the method displayLocation(), the app works, but if I use a external class who extends LocationListener the app do not behave correctly

I know the expected question levels in SO are high but I'm starting my studies about Android development and this issue is taking my sleep away

Btw here is my AndroidManifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.trackit.app.track_it_v002">

    <!--
         The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
         Google Maps Android API v2, but you must specify either coarse or   fine
         location permissions for the 'MyLocation' functionality. 
    -->

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"  />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <!--
         The API key for Google Maps-based APIs is defined as a string     resource.
             (See the file "res/values/google_maps_api.xml").
             Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to sign the APK.
             You need a different API key for each encryption key, including the release key that is used to
             sign the APK for publishing.
             You can define the keys for the debug and release targets in src/debug/ and src/release/. 
        -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MapsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_maps">
            <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Can you guys give me a hand here?

EDIT: after some debugging I've seen the requestLocationUpdates is not returning a non null object and not triggering onLocationChanged(), anyone have a idea why? =S

Comment: A little bump??

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this issue. The mGoogleApiClient object, which needs to be connected at the time of requestLocationUpdates. This was resolved by requestingLocationUpdates from onConnected callback.

```
/*
 * Called first time google client is connected
 */
@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
    Log.v(LOG_TAG,"DetectDrivingService - onConnected");

    // Create
    try {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
    }
    catch(SecurityException se){

    }
}
```